# For loops creating black screen without reading integer array

Tags: java, arrays, canvas, game-engine

Whenever I tried to get the pixel array in the ori class, which extends the Screen class, to render to the canvas (that, in turn, is written in the canvas in the main class) it just generated a black image over the canvas in the JFrame. This only happened when the 'for' loops are written as "x = 0" as opposed to "int x = 0". When the loops are written as "int x = 0" or "int y= 0", it did not generate anything, including the black screen.
This is from the origin method in the ori class:

```
    if(x <= ax && y <= ay){

        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
                pixels[x + y * width] = 0xff00ff;
            }
        }
    }
```

screen class:

```
    void waves(){
            rand = new Random();

    for(y = 0; y < height; y++){

        int r = 24 + 1;
        int s = 10;

        waves++;
        if(waves == 75){
            sel = rand.nextInt(2);
            waves = 0;
        }

        if(sel == 0){

            if(blue > 0){   
                float f = ray - r;

                double uir = f * 0.0001;
                u = blue *= uir;
            }
            else{

            }
        }

        if(sel == 1){

            if(blue > 0){   
                float f = ray + r;
                double uir = f * 0.0001;
                u = blue *= uir;
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        for(x = 0; x < width; x++){

            Color wacol = new Color(0, 0, u);
            int water = wacol.getRGB();

            pixels[x + y * width] = water;
            orga.origin();
        }
    }
}
```

It appears that the 'for' loops written as "x = 0" are called upon and then, somehow, render without reading the pixel array. The same happens when "int x = 0" but with the opposite result. What is causing this and what is causing the code to ignore the pixel array?

Comment: Unless `x` and `y` have been declared previously, that code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: they were declared as static ints in the screen class. sorry I didn't include that.